# crash app when lisnener setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

java activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());


        replaceFragment(new MainFragment());
        NavigationBar();

        ImageButton search = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
   
}
```

when im  assigning a listener for "search" app crashes.

xml fragment

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/search_normal"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```

pls, help

i`ve tried a lot of things.  i`ve watched a lot of videos and  googled i didnt  find the answer

Comment: Please Put the Error Log

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have your **search** `ImageButton` defined inside `MainFragment` layout but you are trying to search it within activity contentView, so in this case `findViewById` returns null and code crashes on `NullPointerException`.

You should move the definition of search ImageButton and the assignment of `OnClickListener` into `MainFragment` code.

Also, when using `viewBindings` you don't have to assign view manually by `findViewById`, you can use it's reference from generated `viewBindings`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a beginner developer so don't be mad